# Filter query based on user in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am trying to filter a m-2-m based on some 3 way relational logic. I have the following models (example only... but the more I write it, it looks like a game I'd like to play...)  Forgive my over use of the `spam` and `eggs` metavariables...

#### Models:

```
class SuperProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForgeignKey('User')
    eggs_unlocked = models.ManyToMany('Egg')
    my_kitchen = models.ForeignKey('SuperKitchen')

class SuperKitchen(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Egg(models.Model):
    eggyness = models.PostiveIntegerField(help_text=_("how Eggy it is. eg." 
                                                      "Spam'n'Eggs is over 9000")
    kitchens = models.ForeignKey(help_text=_('What kitchen carries this')
```

#### Question: As an administrator, in *someone else's* SuperProfileAdmin:

- I want to list what `eggs` they can use based on what `kitchen` they are part of
- A person's `Kitchen` doesn't change, ever.
- `Eggs` only appear in one `kitchen`.
- How do you get an instance of the `SuperProfile` or `SuperKitchen` to filter the `Egg` list for said *other user*

I'm not sure if this is clear, please comment on what needs clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `EggAdmin`, you must override `queryset` method

```
class EggAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    def queryset(self, request):
        kitchen = request.user.superprofile_set.get().my_kitchen #get related users kitchen
        qs = super(EggAdmin, self).queryset(request) #call original queryset method that you are overriding
        return qs.filter(kitchens=kitchen) #apply your filter
```

UPDATE: Ok, that change everything... On SuperPrifile admin, when you open a SuperProfile record, you wish `eggs_unlocked` to be filtered according to that user... So:

```
import re
# grab the superprofile id from the url
sup_pro_rgx=re.compile(r'(\d+)')
sup_pro = sup_pro_rgx.findall(request.META['REQUEST_URI'])[0]
# I know this is really the ugliest way to do this, but there is no other way (at least as far as i know) to do this


class SuperProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
...
def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    if db_field.name == "eggs_unlocked":
        my_kitchen = self.get_object(request, object_id=sup_pro).my_kitchen
        kwargs["queryset"] = Egg.objects.filter(kitchen=my_kitchen)
    return super(SuperProfileAdmin, self).formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

I know, using regex to grab the object id is a really bad practise, but as i mention, that is the only way to do this as i know.

And here is the doc for [formfield_for_manytomany](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_manytomany)

Comment: While this is really helpful, What if I am editing someone else's profile - then the `request.user.superprofile_set.get().my_kitchen` would return the wrong `kitchen`.  Is there a way of accessing the pre-populated values for an already existing model?

Comment: Then instead of `request.user`, you will use that `user`. But this code is written based on you are on **Egg Admin**.

Comment: Ok. Edited the question to clarify where I'm looking for the filter.  How would I get access to said `user` instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
Eggs.objects.filter(kitchens=profile.my_kitchen)
```